# How can I write my own Hadoop scheduler?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, scheduler

I've been studying hadoop's scheduler mechanism recently.
Using 0.20.2(fair&capacity included)
Have read some papers, LATE\Deadline Scheduler...

Has anyone tried?
or is there a guide?

thx anyway

Comment: What functionality are you hoping to provide in your scheduler that is not seen in the existing pluggable M/R schedulers for hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to do your own scheduler maybe you could consider a document from author Datta Dhok - Learning based admission control and task assignment in mapreduce. They did some job on admission control and a learning based hadoop scheduler. Source code is available. Did you find any other documents on these subject?